# Date format in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have table:

Birthday

```
id | name | date
1  | aaa  | 1990-03-02
2  | bbb  | 1990-03-12
3  | ccc  | 1990-03-25
4  | ddd  | 1990-04-25
5  | eee  | 1990-04-23
6  | fff  | 1990-04-26
7  | ggg  | 1990-04-12
```

How is the best way to SELECT all names where date is 1990-04-xx?

Comment: is your date column a date data type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE date LIKE '1990-04%'
```

Some other answers here are assuming you're storing the date in a datefield, but I assumed by the way it was laid out in your question that it was just a string. Going on that assumption, I knew that using the [LIKE operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) would let me use a wildcard (the % sign) to search for anything with that year and month. That said, this query will match anything that starts with 1990-04 so there is a possibility with malformed data that you could get some incorrect data (e.g. a date is entered into the database like '1990-041-12')

Answer (score 2):

If it's a `DATE` value I'd suggest checking if it's between the beginning and the end of the month. If you chop up the date using `DATE_FORMAT` or some other function you'll lose any chance of optimization:

```
SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE `date` BETWEEN '1990-04-01' AND '1990-04-30'
```

If it's a `DATETIME` value, do this instead to account for values like 4/30/1990 at 9PM:

```
SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE `date` >= '1990-04-01' AND `date` < '1990-05-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

If `date` is a `DATE` or `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column and you want an index to have chances to be used:

```
SELECT name
FROM tableX
WHERE date >= '1990-04-01'
  AND date  < '1990-05-01' ;
```

An index on `(date)` would be good. Even better, an index on `(date, name)`.